# Cassandra: Select count of collections

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

I'm looking to see if its possible to select the count how many items are in a collection like:

`SELECT count(emails[]) FROM users WHERE id = '101'`

I can't seem to find how in the docs, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5313

There is no such thing at the moment